# Convert a string into many variables

Tags: raspberry-pi, python-2.x

I want to split a string variable that comes from a gps, like this:

> 2013-08-13T14:33:29.000Z

into:

> year = 2013 month = 08
>   I searched for a long time.

I've tried many things but haven't had any succeeded in getting anything to work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **basic** example of how to do this in Python.

This is neither the most efficient nor the cleanest way to do it, but this illustrates how do split strings and such in a manner that is relevant to a beginning Python programmer.

```
gpsstring = '2013-08-13T14:33:29.000Z'
year = gpsstring.split('T')[0].split('-')[0]
month = gpsstring.split('T')[0].split('-')[1]
day = gpsstring.split('T')[0].split('-')[2]
hour = gpsstring.split('T')[1].split(':')[0]
minute = gpsstring.split('T')[1].split(':')[1]
second = gpsstring.split('T')[1].split(':')[2].split('.')[0]
```

Essentially each variable is being set by splitting the gpsstring. We know where to split the gpsstring because the data you've provided is a standard timestamp interpreted from the [NMEA Timestamp](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/).

Edit - the Timezone info is the end of the string (the 000Z in this case) and can also be grabbed as follows:

```
timezone = gpsstring.split('T')[1].split(':')[2].split('.')[1]
```

Make sense?